# How do I move folders around within Dropbox whilst preserving the file version history?

Tags: dropbox

I want to do a bit of housekeeping within my Dropbox folder. How can I move folders around in such a way that their Dropbox file version history is maintained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. When you move a folder or file to another location, Dropbox process the action as an add and delete. The folder and files start with a clean slate. Any previous version history is attached to the previous location of that folder or file. You can restore deleted items from the previous location and restore different versions of files that way.

If you want Dropbox to maintain file version history across moves, you will need to submit a request for enhancement via their [forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions). I doubt they will implement it as it adds a level of unneeded complexity.